# SAML authentication

Tags: cloudbees

We are looking at IDaaS offerings (OneLogin, Okta, etc.) When we've asked if they support CloudBees they said they do not, but they said if you support SAML authentication that they can add support for CB very easily. Do you know if you support SAML?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific support for SAML - however applications that are hosted on the platform would well support it.

Comment: Michael, is there any API available for creating/updating/deleting user accounts?

Comment: there is http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/OAuth - but I don't believe users/accounts is exposed yet (YET!).

Answer (score 0):

CloudBees supports SAML integration with any SAML IdP endpoint. The SAML IdP endpoint could be running on your premises or you can use IdP providers such as OneLogin, Okta, Centrify etc. they also provide CloudBees app that you can configure for SAML. Both flow - SP initiated or IdP initiated flows are supported as well.

See, http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/09/cloudbees-now-offers-saml-20.html

Answer (score 0):

Centrify definitely has a pre-built SAML app for CloudBees.

You can sign up for free here to test it.

https://www.centrify.com/free-trial/

Comment: spamming not allowed